# rails rjs replacement and swap values

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rjs

I'm trying to figure out how to use RJS to swap between two fields... i know how to replace the values but I can't seem to figure out how to read it.

Is it not possible to read values thru RJS?  Only to replace?

```
<%= link_to_function "Swap" do |page| 
            #to_value = page[:currency_to].value
            page[:currency_from].value = to_value
            page[:currency_to].value = "test"
        end %>
```

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/PrototypeHelper/JavaScriptGenerator/GeneratorMethods.html#M001664

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested both of the following.

```
<%= link_to_function "Swap", 'var tmp_frm = $("#currency_from").val();
                              var tmp_to = $("#currency_to").val();
                              $("#currency_from").val(tmp_to);
                              $("#currency_to").val(tmp_frm);'%>
```

or better yet

```
<%= link_to_function "Swap", 'var tmp_frm = $("#currency_from").val();
                              $("#currency_from").val($("#currency_to").val());
                              $("#currency_to").val(tmp_frm);'%>
```

depending on your html, you may need to remove the pound symbols

```
<%= link_to_function "Swap", 'var tmp_frm = $("currency_from").value;
                                      var tmp_to = $("currency_to").value;
                                      $("currency_from").value = tmp_to;
                                      $("currency_to").value = tmp_frm;'%>
```

Comment: Ah, great.  That did it.  or almost, the idea was right but for some reason neither of those worked, I had to slightly modify it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about prototype or rjs, but a quick look at the prototype API shows a [getValue()](http://api.prototypejs.org/dom/form/element.html#getvalue-class_method). I would think this has to do with `page[:currency_to]` returning a prototype element as opposed to just a DOM element.

Maybe try replacing

```
to_value = page[:currency_to].value
```

with

```
to_value = page[:currency_to].getValue()
```

Can you just use whatever javascript you want in rjs files? My guess is no, since it's Ruby 'rendering' Javascript.

The section of the Rails API you linked to is a bit misleading I think. They don't seem to be referring to an actual 'value', they just use value as the name to be passed to the block.

Comment: yeah... no it doesn't seem to work.  its very easy to set things and make things happen, but reading things seems difficult.  i can't seem to find any examples.

Answer (score 0):

```
<%= link_to_function "Swap", 'var tmp_frm = $("currency_from").value;
                                      var tmp_to = $("currency_to").value;
                                      $("currency_from").value = tmp_to;
                                      $("currency_to").value = tmp_frm;'%>
```